# ASP.Net Core gRPC Unable to see the reflection methods in grpcurl

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc

I'm using ASP.Net Core 3.1 to expose Api methods via gRPC. I have added the following in Startup.cs:

````
            {
                endpoints.MapGrpcReflectionService();
                endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<EmployeeService>();
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<ProductionService>();
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<LookupService>();
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<SalesService>();                
            });

            app.UseGrpcWeb();

            //Configure gRPC
            services.AddGrpc(options =>
            {
                options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            });
            services.AddGrpcReflection();```

However, when I try to list the available methods from grpcurl using the below command, I don't see the above service methods reflected except the default one.

`grpc -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" -connect-timeout 30 -plaintext localhost:5701 describe`

Response:
`grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection is a service:...`
````

Comment: Could you please tell what is AddGrpcReflection?  Please post more details information about this.

Comment: It's an extension method available in Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Reflection nuget package.